# Lookups in lists / set and modification of elements

Tags: python, list, set, lookup, nested-lists

I have created a function which finds if the items inside the lists are common and if they are then i modify specific elements inside those lists(lists are nested). Problem is that lookups inside the list is O(n). If I have huge lists I spend too much time on lookups. Here is the function using lists:

```
def union_finder(list_of_lists_unions):
    while list_of_lists_unions:
        processed_list = list_of_lists_unions.pop(0)
        for item in processed_list:
            for loc_list,pointer_list in enumerate(list_of_lists_unions):
                for location,iteration in enumerate(pointer_list):
                    if item == iteration:
                        #if condition then change the element which matches on the lists
                        if(something):    
                            count +=1
                            index_dict[item] = count
                            list_of_lists_unions[loc_list][location] = str(index_dict[item]) + str('@')
```

The function works perfectly. For example if I put as an input this:

> [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19,
>   20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30], [1, 2, 3, 4, 29, 30],
>   [100, 200, 300, 28, 29, 30]]

**EDIT**

I am trying to use set(), because the lookup complexity is O(1) (as the documentation says). The thing is that I was using lists so I can modify the elements inside the iterations. Sets don't let me modify specific elements inside them. My idea is to locate the items I want inside the set, then cast it back to a list make the modifications I want and then recast it back to set. But is this efficient ? Is there any other way to use the set's lookup speed? List's complexity for lookups is O(N) which is too much because my lists somethimes are pretty long and if I try to compare the 2 lists len(list1) = m, len(list2) = n , I get m*n lookups (x in s).

Comment: What do you mean by *"lookup"* - you seem to be *indexing* the lists, which is `O(1)`.

Comment: by lookup i mean search (x in s)

Comment: instead of casting, why not maintain a list AND a set, use the former for writing and the latter for lookups

Comment: I think you are right. I will try it.